# Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined on Run in Titanium

Tags: windows, titanium

I'm writing an simple Ajax communications in Javascript in Titanium. Yesterday night this application is worked correctly, but now, it thrown for me an error:

> [INFO] :   JavaScript files need to be encrypted
>   2016-06-02T10:27:22.859Z | ERROR  | An uncaught exception was thrown!
>   Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined 2016-06-02T10:27:22.860Z |
>   ERROR  | Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined

Here is my code:

```
var valasz = "";
var ajax = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onerror: function(e) {
        alert('Error!');
    },
    onload : function(e) {
        valasz = this.responseText;
        if (valasz.length > 0) {
            var Gyartosorok = valasz.split("\t");
            var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
                title : "Termékkereső",
                backgroundColor: "#ddd",
                exitOnClose: true
            });
            var gyartosor_picker = Titanium.UI.createPicker({
                top: 4,
                height: 36,
                backgroundColor: "#000",
                width: "75%",
                selectionIndicator: true
            });
            var GyartosorData = [];
            var GyartosorDataIndex = 0;
            if (Gyartosorok.length > 1) {
                GyartosorData[0] = Titanium.UI.createPickerRow({ title: "Összes sor", val: "0" });
                GyartosorDataIndex++;
            }
            for (i = 0; i < Gyartosorok.length; i++) {
                GyartosorData[GyartosorDataIndex] = Titanium.UI.createPickerRow({ title: Gyartosorok[i], val: Gyartosorok[i] });
                GyartosorDataIndex++;
            }
            gyartosor_picker.add(GyartosorData);
            var keresendoInput = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
                top: 42,
                height: 36,
                width: "75%",
                backgroundColor: "#fff",
                borderColor: "#000",
                color: "#000",
                borderStyle: Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
                hintText: "Termékkód (részlet)"
            });
            var keresesGomb = Titanium.UI.createButton({
                title: "Keresés",
                width: "60%",
                top: 80
            });
            win.add(gyartosor_picker);
            win.add(keresendoInput);
            win.add(keresesGomb);
            win.open();
        } else {
            alert("No data!");
        }
    },
    timeout: 5000
});
ajax.open("POST", "http://xyz.hu/dir/dir/ajax.php");
ajax.send({
    'mod' : 1
});
```

Please, help me. What is wrong!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This error is generated after I click on Run button, and the translate process is begining.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, something was wrong in Titanium, because after I selected my all sourcecode, closed this project and opened a new project and paste my code to app.js, then this error is missed and my application is working successful!

Thanks for your patient!

Comment: Glad that you solved this issue on your own. Please mark this answer as accepted (the green tick below the answer counter on the left). This shows other users that your problem is solved.

Comment: Oh, sorry! Thanks for your warning, Robin!

Comment: Ops. The stackoverflow.com sad to me, when I click to green tick:
_You can accept your answer in 2 days_
So, I will mark this at soon.

Comment: Since the question does not really have an answer and thus is not helpful for future users consider deleting the question.

Answer (score 0):

Clean build : Clean the project and than build the project

in Appceletor studio go to project=>clean and than run make sure that in project drop-down  menu build automatically is checked.